# Bool variable changing value, but I can't figure out why

Tags: c#, datagridview

When the DataGridView in my application is populated, the following method is fired:

```
        public void OrderSelectionChanged()
    {
        ConfirmOrCancelChangesDialog();

        // Get values from selected order and populate controls
        if (view.OrderTable.SelectedRows.Count != 0)
        {
            OrderViewObject ovm = (OrderViewObject)view.OrderTable.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;
            selectedOrder = orderModel.GetOrderById(ovm.OrderId);

            // Populate view controls with data from selected order
            view.OrderID = selectedOrder.Id.ToString();
     ---->> view.OrderDateCreated = selectedOrder.DateCreated; <<-----
            view.OrderDeliveryDate = selectedOrder.DeliveryDate;

            PopulateOrderAddressControls(selectedOrder.Address);

            PopulateOrderItemTableControl();
            PopulateOrderWeightAndSumControls();

            view.OrderNote = selectedOrder.Note;

            // Enable buttons
            view.DeleteOrderButtonEnabled = true;
            view.NewOrderItemButtonEnabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            view.DeleteOrderButtonEnabled = false;
        }
    }
```

For some reason, the "isSaved" variable is being changed from true to false at the row I marked with arrows and I can't figure out why. This is not supposed to happen and was never an issue before, but suddenly appeared.

The variable "isSaved" is being checked in the following method:

```
        public void ConfirmOrCancelChangesDialog()
    {
        if (!isSaved)
        {
            DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show(Properties.Resources.SaveChanges,
                Properties.Resources.SaveChangesTitle, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

            if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                SaveOrder();
            }
            else
            {
                UndoChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is causing the save or cancel dialog to appear everytime the application is started, which obviously is wrong. Since the selection changed method is fired three times and isSaved is changed during the first run, the dialog pops up during the second time around. Through debugging step by step I could figure out at what point isSaved is changing, but not how or why.

View is the form, OrderDateCreated is a getter/setter for a DateTimePicker, selectedOrder is just an order object and DateCreated a Date. Am I missing something here?

Cheers!

Comment: It changes on *exactly* that line?  And you've confirmed this by stepping through the debugger and examining the value of `isSaved` before and after that one line is executed?  Where is `isSaved` defined?

Comment: Where else is the `isSaved` variable referenced? We really need to see more context.

Comment: Does `isSaved` have a special `set` method of any kind?

Comment: The code I see shouldn't change 'isSaved' at the by you specified line, can you add all references to 'isSaved'?

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint inside isSaved to see what exactly is changing it? Maybe there's an event that changes the value (ex: if the property gets changed, then the variable is set to false).

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me in the right direction. Through the references I could figure out, that isSaved was changed through an event being fired when the view.OrderDateCreated text was changed. Don't even remember putting it in there, but now it's fixed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem related to your code setting values to `view` object.
If you didn't create properties by your own, that object may have `set` properties which detects any change and setting the `isSaved` properties to false.

Try this workaround:

```
bool wasSaved = isSaved; //reference properly to your isSaved variable, and store it in the wasSaved local var

view.OrderID = selectedOrder.Id.ToString();
view.OrderDateCreated = selectedOrder.DateCreated;
view.OrderDeliveryDate = selectedOrder.DeliveryDate;

isSaved = wasSaved; //revert to the previous state
```